# DI/IoC container vs factories: Where do I configure my application and why?

Tags: configuration, factory, ioc-containers

I am trying to figure out when to use the DIC/IoC registry for configuring my software and when to use factories, along with the reasoning behind either approach.

---

I am using StructureMap as my DI container (DIC), which is easy to configure using registries. In the DIC practically all registered objects are static in the sense, that I do not need to change/exchange any implementation/instance at runtime, once the DIC is configured and they are configured in the DIC as singletons. However, since my software (SW) will run on different devices I *do need* to select a device-specific registry depending on the device that my SW runs on in order to configure the hardware accordingly.

Since the construction of some my objects requires reading in configuration files, I am using factories to return these instances to the DIC, in order to separate the reading of the configuration from the creation of the object. I registered the factory getters in the DIC for the corresponding plugin types.

Now say I have a plugin type `IMotor` with concrete types `Motor1` and `Motor2`, which should be handled by a factory. There are now two ways I can decide how to configure my device:

1. I pass information about the device that the SW is running on to a `MotorFactory` and it returns the correct motor, either `Motor1` or `Motor2`. In this case the logic for deciding is *inside* the Factory.
2. I configure the DIC according to the device it is running on and create two factories `Motor1Factory` and `Motor2Factory`, where one creates `Motor1` and the other  `Motor2`. In this case I would have differing registry entries for `IMotor` in the device-specific registries which use either `Motor1Factory` or `Motor2Factory`.

Now my question is: Which one of these two methods are preferable and why? To me, it seems the first case is not straight forward and a convoluted, since I am spreading out the logic that decides what type to instantiate throughout the code-base. Whereas in the second case I am effectively multiplying the number of factories in my code, since I will need a factory for (almost) each concrete type. It becomes even more confusing to me, when abstract factories are added to the mix.

So again: When should I use one method or the other? And more importantly: What are good indicators for deciding which way to go?

Comment: Which way is simpler?  Do the benefits of the more complex approach outweigh the cost of the additional complexity?

Answer (score 2):

If you use both I will go for something simple :

- DI/IoC : for every configuration that won't changed at runtime.
- Factory : for creating instance of objects at runtime which depends of runtime input parameters. The instances of the factory are injected by the DI container.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract factories are used when you have objects related through a hierarchy that needs to vary together. I don't see that here.

What I see is that you are wondering if a factory should choose the motor or if the DIC should choose a factory that produces a particular motor.

It's hard to choose precisely because a factory and a DIC do very similar things. The difference is the factory is focused on a particular issue and the DIC is more general.

It comes down to this question: *do you have a need for code that is particular to this issue that will live in the factory?* Or *is it more general like reading configuration details from a file?*

Keep in mind that while you may only be choosing between `Motor1` and `Motor2` today, tomorrow there may be a `Motor3`. Favour the design that would make `Motor3` easy to add.

Answer (score 0):

I would seperate the logic "which motor to use" into a special Factory called [Builder (pattern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) 
and use the IOC-Container for both motors as implementaton detail of the builder.

As a general rule:

- you need a factory (or a builder) if you have to create many dynamic objects of the class/interface. (i.e. for every car you produce you have to create one new motor)
- if you need only one static instance of a class the ioc/di can do the job for you (i.e you need only one static instance of the paymentservice and one static instance of the MotorBuilderService)